# singular points of vector field in the ball

Tags: differential-geometry

There is a vector field $v$ in $n$-dimensional ball $B^n$. The field is pointing in the inward normal direction on the boundary $S^{n-1}$. What can one say about the number and type of singular points, which the vector field $v$ would have in the ball, in general position? Is there necessarily singular points of sink type in the ball?